# Looking for the name and a way to generate this type of graphs for web

Tags: graph, graphics, data-visualization, diagram, graph-visualization

[image]

If I understand it correctly the key difference with a regular clustered tree is forming (potentially nesting) groups by an arbitrary 3rd parameter that is not directly related to the links between nodes.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at http://viz-js.com/
other similar pages for GraphViz exists